# How to properly find code in code base that is present on the web browser

Tags: c#, html, angular, visual-studio, webapi

As a programmer that is new to a job and a brand new code base, I am having trouble connecting the codebase to the page I have navigated to. What is the best way to find the HTML in my code base that is being used in the web browser?

I run the project locally and navigate in the browser to the specified location in the bug. Now I need to fix that issue in the code base.

I am able to utilize the network tab to find the endpoints, but I need to go to the page in the front end.

- Using Visual Studio Code
- Web API
- Angular
- C#

Answer (score 0):

**1. Method using inspect element**

Most of the time inspect element is enough though, since you will see most of the `selector` names there, and could also look for certain css classes or ids and then look them up in your code.

---

**2. Method using the official browser plugin**

You can install the Angular Devtools plugin [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/devtools) (with links on where to get the it) in Chromium based or Firefox browsers.

When opening the browsers devtools there should then be a new tab called `Angular`.

With it you can see the component tree of your current view and its elements. There you will be able to see the `selector` name of the components and can search for the component inside your project.

---

**Note:** The second method only works on dev builds of your Angular application, whereas the second method works everywhere and with any framework or library you might encounter in the future (e.g. Vue, React etc.).

Also keep in mind that this only works with HTML. Many bugs you might encounter could happen inside your JavaScript/TypeScript and would be needed to search for differntly most of the time.